# Grails Databinding Dateformat

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a problem within a grails 2.5 application, when it comes to data binding and correct date formats.
I have this formats of date that i want to bind.

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
    'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
    'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',
    "dd/MM/yyyy'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'",
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S',
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"
]
```

All other are working properly but only this two not working:

```
'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm','dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not working but the docs state that `The formats specified in grails.databinding.dateFormats will be attempted in the order in which they are included in the List` so is it possible that a format positioned earlier in the list is taking precedence when matching? http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#dataBinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Mike W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6544083/mike-w) yes you are right I just changed my order and it is working fine.

Now:

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
    'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',
    'dd/MM/yyyy',
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
    'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S',
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"
]
```